# How to take mutable references to struct fields in a method and call other methods without the borrow checker complaining?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have this code:

```rust
struct Player {}

impl Player {
    fn update(&mut self) {}
}

struct GameBoard {
    p1: Player,
    p2: Player,
}

impl GameBoard {
    fn update(&mut self) {}
    fn update_current_player(&mut self, p1_turn: bool) {
        if p1_turn {
            self.p1.update()
        } else {
            self.p2.update();
        }

        self.update();

        if p1_turn {
            self.p1.update()
        } else {
            self.p2.update();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to not type out the `if` statement every time I want to update the current player.  In other languages I've used, I would write something like this:

```rust
struct Player {}

impl Player {
    fn update(&mut self) {}
}

struct GameBoard {
    p1: Player,
    p2: Player,
}

impl GameBoard {
    fn update(&mut self) {}
    fn update_current_player(&mut self, p1_turn: bool) {
        let p = if p1_turn { &mut self.p1 } else { &mut self.p2 };
        p.update();

        self.update();

        p.update();
    }
}
```

But this annoys the borrow checker:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:18:9
   |
15 |         let p = if p1_turn { &mut self.p1 } else { &mut self.p2 };
   |                                                    ------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
...
18 |         self.update();
   |         ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
19 | 
20 |         p.update();
   |         - first borrow later used here
```

There must be some way not to have to type out the `if` statement every time.  I would also prefer not to break the `if` statement out into a function that takes `p1_turn`, because writing out the function call is still fairly long.  Does anyone have suggestions?

I understand why this pattern is unsafe if you're accessing data inside an `Enum` or on the heap, since the call to `self.update()` might invalidate the reference, but in this case the reference can't possibly be made invalid by any code in `self.update()` because it's just referring to a field of the struct.

Comment: `enum`s and pointers aren't the only reason why this is unsafe. The compiler is permitted to optimize `update_current_player` by assuming that `p` is not aliased during its lifetime, which might include omitting redundant loads and stores -- instructions that would become very *not* redundant if another reference (`self`) is being used concurrently to access the same data. You can opt out of those optimizations, using one of the "interior mutability" types (`Cell`, `RefCell`, `Mutex`, `RwLock` etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There must be some way not to have to type out the `if` statement every time. I would also prefer not to break the `if` statement out into a function that takes `p1_turn`, because writing out the function call is still fairly long.

Given those requirements you can create an anonymous closure which captures the `p1_turn` variable and re-use that. However, to avoid overlapping mutable borrows you'd have to pass `&mut self` as an argument to the closure. Example:

```rust
struct Player {}

impl Player {
    fn update(&mut self) {}
}

struct GameBoard {
    p1: Player,
    p2: Player,
}

impl GameBoard {
    fn update(&mut self) {}
    fn update_current_player(&mut self, p1_turn: bool) {
        let p_update = |gb: &mut GameBoard| {
            if p1_turn {
                gb.p1.update();
            } else {
                gb.p2.update();
            }
        };

        p_update(self);
        self.update();
        p_update(self);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c19c0700ccebad3b422c94ae7ca951fa)